# inheritdoc for individual parameter?

Tags: c#, xml, documentation

I want to use [inheritdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#inheritdoc) to grab the description of a parameter. So I have:

```
/// <param name="nameOfParameter">parameter description</param>
MethodName(int nameOfParameter)`
...
/// <summary>
/// <inheritdoc cref="ClassName.MethodName" select="param[@name='nameOfParameter']" />
/// </summary>
AnotherFunc
```

But AnotherFunc now has the description of `MethodName` rather than the parameter. Is this possible?

Comment: Code documentation isn't that complex.  Don't be lazy.  Just copy and paste the text from one place to another.

Comment: 1. Yes it is. Inheritdoc allows select arguments such as selecting particular span ids and can filter on params in some ways (linked above). 2. It's not lazy, it's basic DRY and everything that entails. 3. Avoiding copy paste is the entire purpose of inheritdoc.

Comment: @Neil: The example here is not that complex, but real life documentation may be quite large and with repeating information. I use such inheritdoc tags to extract parts of existing documentation very often. The main advantage is that it gets updated on all places when I edit just the source comment. This has nothing to do with lazyness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `select` attribute is no longer used in [inheritdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#inheritdoc) tag. Use `path` instead:

```
/// <summary>
/// <inheritdoc cref="ClassName.MethodName" path="/param[@name='nameOfParameter']" />
/// </summary>
void AnotherFunc() { }
```

UPDATE

The xpath above will also include the inherited <param> tag itself inside the <summary> tag. It's not visible in the Intellisense quick info. But the more appropriate xpath should insert just the contents of the inherited <param> tag:

```
/// <summary>
/// <inheritdoc cref="MethodName" path="//param[@name='nameOfParameter']/node()" />
/// </summary>
void AnotherFunc() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't completely succeed using @Peter's answer though it pointed me in the right direction.

I was successful with the following syntax (C# 7.3, VS 2022):

```
///<summary>
///Description of method here.
///</summary>
///<inheritdoc cref="crefedMethod(parmtype,parmtype)" path="/param[@name='parmName']"/>
```

This results in the `parmName` parameter's doc being inherited.

Additionally the following syntax results in any matching (by name) parameters being inherited:

```
///<summary>
///Description of method here.
///</summary>
///<inheritdoc cref="crefedMethod(parmtype,parmtype)" path="/param"/>
```